# Trello.post via client.js API?

Tags: javascript, ajax, trello

I'm trying to use the API of Trello via the library they provide, client.js:https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/clientjs.html

I have:

```
<script src="./js/jQuery.js"></script>
<script src="https://api.trello.com/1/client.js?key=myAPIInsertedHere"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
Trello.authorize({
    interactive: true,
    type: "popup",
    expiration: "never",
    name: "surveyrequest",
    persist: "true",
    success: function() { onAuthorizeSuccessful(); },
    error: function() { onFailedAuthorization(); },
    scope: { read: true, write: true},
});

function onAuthorizeSuccessful() {
    var token = Trello.token();     
    today = new Date("December 25, 2015 12:00:00");
    var thisUrl = encodeURL = "http://www.google.com/";
    console.log(token);
    Trello.post("cards", { name: "Card created for test", desc: "this is a test",  idlist: "myIDListInsertedHere", due: today, urlSource: thisUrl});

}

function onFailedAuthorization() {
    console.log("Authorization failed.");
}
});
</script>
```

MyAPIInsertedHere and myIDListInsertedHEre are replaced with the actual values.

Console.log shows a valid value for token however the POST command gets rejected, it says:
POST https://api.trello.com/1/cards 400 (Bad Request)

As far as I can tell from the documentation for this (https://trello.com/docs/api/card/#post-1-cards) I am formatting this correctly...any ideas to what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: If you specify only the `name` and the `idList` does it work then?  If you look at response to the request in the Chrome network inspector, can you see the error message that was returned?

Comment: No, it does not, I've tried every possible combination of parameters. The Chrome console says  POST https://api.trello.com/1/cards 400 (Bad Request) as does the respsonse headers, but no more detail than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post request is showing an invalid value for `idList` since the parameter name has a lowercase "L" in your request.  If you capitalize that, it should work fine.

Comment: You are right! I had one other mistake: var thisUrl = encodeURL = "http://www.google.com/"; It should have been: var thisUrl = encodeURI("http://www.google.com/");

It's amazing how something as simple as not capitalizing 1 single letter sets me back countless hours. Thanks so much for your assistance.